# get button width at auto size width in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button, width

Hi I want my button in my C# WPF program to autosize depending on content. This is what I already mentioned. 
But now I want to know what width the button actually got. 
I tried `button.ActualWidth` and `button.width`. The first returned "0" and the second returned "NaN".

My XAML for the button

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,41,433,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" Click="button1_Click"/>
```

New content of my button:

```
button1.Content = "new content xayxax ";

nWidth = button.ActualWidth;
MessageBox.Show(nWidth.ToString());
```

This Messagebox displays "0"

Comment: `ActualWidth` works reliably in my experience. Please add enough code for us to reproduce the issue. Please add it as text in your question, not as a linik to a screenshot.

Comment: Actually there is no link to a screenshot...

Comment: Good. Let's keep it that way. Please add the code. [Here's a guide to writing questions that can be answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why would you expect the width of `button` to change when you change the content of `button1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Sinatr (+1) you need to measure the `Button` after you have set its `Content` property - or wait until WPF measures it for you - but make sure that you use an large enough available space when you measure it:

```
button1.Content = "new content xayxax ";
var size = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
button1.Measure(size);
button1.Arrange(new Rect(button1.DesiredSize));
MessageBox.Show(button1.ActualWidth.ToString());
```

This should display "110,703" which is the actual size of the `Button` after its `Content` has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

`ActualWidth` should never be `NaN` (it starts from `0` before measure and arrange) , but `Width` can. `Width == NaN` means control width wasn't [locally set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) and the control actual size will depends on layout.

Use `ActualWidth` to get width of control *after* measure and arrange:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Content = "123";
button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
button.Measure(new Size(100, 100));
button.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
MessageBox.Show(button.ActualWidth.ToString()); // Output: 23,41
```

You don't event need a window (the way how WPF engine works), but you must to call `Measure` and `Arrange`.

Changing `Content` will not *refresh* the control, that would occurs some time later, you can invoke the call like this to get it:

```
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Content = "123";
    //MessageBox.Show(button.ActualWidth.ToString()); // output: 0
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show(button.ActualWidth.ToString()), DispatcherPriority.Render); // correct output
}
```

First message box will still display old size, new size become available only measure/arrange. Invoke with `DispatcherPriority.Render` will ensure what render occurs (it will do measure/arrange), returning correct new size.

If you can't wait with invoke, then just call `Measure` and `Arrange` yourself (passing parent container available size, or just invoking it on the root element of visual tree).